# Translate Unicode Literal in Qt 5.3

Tags: c++, qt, unicode, globalization, non-ascii-characters

In a Qt 5.3 application, I have a string literal that contains non-ASCII characters (specifically German Umlauts) that will need to be translated into foreign languages. So I have two issues: (1) I have to mark that literal with tr() and (2) I have to display the string correctly on the screen for which I would seem to have to use QString::fromLatin1() or some such function.

If I do

```
QString s = tr("ä");
```

the string is marked for translation but will not display right.

If I do

```
QString r = QString::fromLatin1("ä");
```

the string will display right but will not be marked for translation.

How can I combine the two into one? And yes, my source file is saved in UTF8 encoding.

I've been searching up and down the forums and none of the hints work; mainly because most of the solutions apply to Qt 4.8 and have been removed or depreciated for Qt 5.3. Thank you for your help!!

PS: I'm developing using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 8. According to VS2010 and Notepad++ my sources are saved in UTF8 with BOM encoding.

Comment: Probably because `tr` is equivalent (if not `#define`'d) to `QString::fromUtf8`. The translation tool is pretty stupid and just looks for `tr("...")`; it would be fooled by `#undef tr, #define tr(x) QString::fromLatin1(x)`

Answer (score 4):

If using `QString::fromLatin1("ä")` you get a correct output then your source files haven't UTF-8 encoding.

When source file

```
printf("%x\n", QString("ä").at(0).unicode());
printf("%x\n", QString::fromLatin1("ä").at(0).unicode());
```

has UTF-8 encoding, then output is

```
e4
c3
```

but when Latin1 (ISO-8859-1), then

```
fffd
e4
```

`e4` is the Unicode code of the letter `ä` (U+00E4)

Comment: Thank you for that. The output is indeed what you describe as Latin1 encoding (fffd and e4) but every text editor I use to look at my file tells me it is encoded as UTF-8. I don't know what to do now ...?

Comment: Try to open a source file in a text editor (Qt Creator, NPP, ...), select right encoding that will display strings correctly and convert encoding of this source file to UTF-8 with BOM.

Comment: I used several text editors (among them Qt Creator and NPP) to convert the file into UTF-8 and into Latin1 and run your code. In both encodings, I get the result "fffd\ne4". Therefore, the test you suggest does not seem to work.

Comment: Please add in your question what system, toolchain and etc. you use.

Comment: I added to my question that I'm using VS2010 on Windows 8. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Read documentation of [trUtf8](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#trUtf8) ([deprecated/obsolete in Qt5](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject-obsolete.html#trUtf8)).
So you don't have to use this function, just set proper default codec. Add i main this line:

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForTr("UTF-8");
```

If you prefer avoid changing default codec just use `trUtf8` instead of `tr`.

Comment: Well, that's the problem ... trUtf8 is deprecated and the change in codec is removed entirely in Qt5.3. So these two methods do not work.

Comment: ups I didn't investigate how deep are differences between Qt4 and Qt5 in this mater.